# jqueryvalidation plugin isn't properly aligning errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery validator plugin with Bootstrap 3 to validate my form inputs. It works great but when user enters any wrong input the alignment gets messed up.

**Screenshots**

Before: http://oi58.tinypic.com/23sta4p.jpg
After: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2pq17a8.jpg

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some custom valdiation display fro Jquery validation
This is the solution you need, you can use the errorPlacement method to override where to put the error message

```
$("form").validate({
            highlight: function(e) {
                $(e).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error")
            },
            unhighlight: function(e) {
                $(e).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error")
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "help-block",
            errorPlacement: function(e, t) {
                if (t.parent(".input-group").length) {
                    e.insertAfter(t.parent())
                } else {
                    e.insertAfter(t)
                }
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
  highlight: function(e) {